# Git: Clone repository that contains itself (adds itself as submodule)

Tags: windows, git, github, clone, git-submodules

I am trying to clone this repository:
https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL
But almost all of the submodules are adding this repository as a submodule! (see: https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/tree/master/test/packages)

This creates an infinite recursion, and it keeps cloning forever.

Is there a solution for this?!

Comment: Passers-by might want to also read [_Circular submodule dependency causes recursive clones or submodule updates to fail #301_](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/issues/301#issue-473450451)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The infinite recursion happens if you specify the `--recurse-submodules` option to `git clone`. As a workaround, you could:

Clone the repository without submodules:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:electronicarts/EASTL.git
$ cd EASTL
```

And then initialize and update the submodules without recursion:

```
$ git submodule update --init
```